# How to use external API in sharepoint online or in SPFX?

Tags: rest, spfx, api

I am trying to integrate the Microsoft Translator Text API to a SharePoint online site, and the method that I am using is with sharepoint framework webpart. but when I press the button to do the API call and error is popping up:

> "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
>   doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a
>   preflight request".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958649/1452528